# How do I gain freedom in Succubox?

Tags: succubox

I need to know how to gain freedom in Succubox, as the title says. Is anyone able to answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you get jailed for going to the console you will earn 1 freedom upon leaving jail which has a default timer of 1 hour.

Comment: I also got jailed when I reached level 101... The cyber police turned up and asked me a few questions about the loot boxes I claimed to have bought earlier... I told them I paid when I didn't earlier in the game and when the cyber police turned up I was honest and so they threw me in jail. :(